# Know which list item is clicked on a master page from content page

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net

I have the below unordered list on a master page

```
<ul class="nav nav-second-level" id ="translist">
    <li>
        <a href="Deposit.aspx">Deposit</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="Deposit.aspx">Withdrawal</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Both will call the same page but based on which item is selected, I will populate the same page with dynamic data and keep that information in asp.net session variable or something to use later at server side.
Please assist

Comment: You want to detect which item is selected when the link is clicked?

Comment: Yes, detect which one is selected  and use that to populate the Deposit.aspx page on page load

Answer (score 0):

You could use the onclick attribute and specify what to do in javascript

```
<a href="Deposit.aspx" onclick="function1()">Deposit</a>

<a href="Deposit.aspx" onclick="function2()">Deposit</a>
```

then implement function1 & function2 in javascript

Comment: Thanks Sam,but please am a beginner so I will need some more help.In the Master Page javascript I want to store a value related to what was clicked  and use it in Deposit.aspx when it finally loads

Comment: Am thinking of if  I pass this value to the URL and access it on Deposit.aspx Page load like Request.Querystring or theres a better solution